# How would I use python to print out alternating upper and lower case letters that the user has input?

Tags: python, loops

I need to take an input from the user and save it.

All the **originally uppercase** letters there need to be converted **to lowercase** letters;

and the **originally lowercase** letters in that input are to be converted **to uppercase** ones.

It sometimes seems to be quite hard to figure out what commands to use and how to use them.

To explain better, the string `"OvErFLOW"` would be transformed to `"oVeRflow"`

I *also* need to put some random symbol between the letters obtained from the conversion, and this is mainly the part that one may be now struggling with.

Help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a bit vague. Please provide clear examples of input/output, the detailed logic, and most importantly what you tried and how it eventually failed.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing sample input, expected output, and _code_ for what you've tried based on your own research, so that we can better understand how to help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Hello, World!")
i = input()
a = ""
b = "" 
for Ih in i:
    if Ih == Ih.upper():
        a += Ih.lower ()
    elif Ih == Ih.lower():
        a += Ih.upper() 
print(a)
for i in a:
    b += i + "r" #insert random
```

Print out b and see the result!